# Slow queries searching for records starting at an earliest datetime using C# SDK and dashboard

Tags: c#, splunk

I’m having problems with slow queries when returning a fixed number of events starting from a specified earliest datetime, from an index/sourcetype containing tens to hundreds of millions of records. E.g.:

```
index=test sourcetype=touch_tuio earliest="09/29/2015:00:00:00" | fields _time,host,screen_id,tuio_type
```

Using the SDK and a maximum limit of 50000 events, because events appear in descending date order and are cropped at 50000, we only get the ***latest*** 50000 values which do not start at the requested earliest date. So in this case the resulting date range of the above query is "from": 2015-10-13T12:30:14 "to": 2015-10-13T13:08:41. (where 2015-10-13T13:08:41 is the most recent record in Splunk).

If I use **tail**, I get the correct values (in ascending date order) starting at the correct earliest datetime, but then the query time is unacceptably long in both C# SDK and dashboard (and will take longer and longer with increasing data). E.g.

```
index=test sourcetype=touch_tuio earliest="09/29/2015:00:00:00" | fields _time,host,screen_id,tuio_type | tail 50000
```

In the dashboard, even a query such as below takes a very long time, looking for 10 records starting at a particular date:

```
index=test sourcetype=touch_tuio earliest="09/29/2015:00:00:00" | fields _time,host,screen_id,tuio_type | tail 10
```

It seems that Splunk needs to go through **EVERY** record just to give me 10 records starting at a specific date (09/29/2015:00:00:00). This takes an extreme amount of time.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong here?
Is there another way to query a fixed number of events beginning at a selected earliest date, without using tail, or without the increasing search time?

Thank you!